# How to merge the two dataframes based on column value in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes where one column value is same in both the dataframes. I want to merge the dataframes based on this column

```
df1:
ColA  ColB  
D123  200   
D123  200  

df2:
----
ColC  ColD 
D123  400   
D123  400
```

But I want output in the format like

```
ColA  ColB  ColD
D123  200   400
D123  200   400
```

How can I do that in python using pandas.

I am not getting the format when I am using the pd.merge

Comment: Do you need `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` ?

Comment: @jezrael No I tried that.

Comment: Tested `df = (pd.concat([df1.set_index('ColA'), 
                 df2.set_index('ColC')], axis=1)
        .reset_index()
        )` and for me working correct. Please change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for show why `concat` not working